# Induction with sets: $\forall n \ge 1: \overline{\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i}=\bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{A_i}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I know how to do induction with equations, but for this thing with sets:

$$\forall n \ge 1: \overline{\bigcap\nolimits_{i=1}^nA_i}=\bigcup\nolimits_{i=1}^n \overline{A_i}$$

exactly I don't have an idea. If someone can I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way.  First, look at the base case, which is $n=1$. It is easy.  Now do $n=2$-can you verify that?  Finally, assume it is true for values up to $n$.  When you write the equation for $n+1$, note that associativity lets you group the first $n$ terms on each side into one set of parentheses, and you have the two element case.

Answer (score 4):

It’s the same idea exactly. For your induction step you’ll assume that $$\overline{\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i}=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\overline{A_i}$$ and try to use this induction hypothesis to show that

$$\overline{\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1}A_i}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}\overline{A_i}\;.$$

HINT: You’ll use the fact that you already know the case $n=2$: it’s one of the De Morgan laws, $\overline{X\cap Y}=\overline{X}\cup\overline{Y}$.

Comment: You may want to know about the `\nolimits` command, which I used to produce the equation in the main post.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: My preference is the exact opposite: I tend to use `\limits` for in-line text when it doesn’t completely louse up the spacing.

Comment: Yes, so do I. But in this case, `\overline` looks awkward (to me) because of the positioning of the limits. I just pointed it out because it could've been a result of not knowing, instead of a conscious choice.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I’m not terribly keen on the way either of them displays, to tell you the truth, and I don’t really like using a complement operator in a set-theoretic context. If I hadn’t wanted to accommodate the OP, I’d have specified a universal set and written $$X\setminus\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^n(X\setminus A_i)\;.$$

Comment: AGH. At first glance I thought this problem was nonsense, because I *never* use overbar for complement. Those of us who use this notation for closure are perennially confused by the textbook authors who us it for complement.